# what is difference between "someurl/?a=2" and "someurl?a=2"

Tags: php, url

i know that we can send variables in url by this syntax:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2
```

and i know that we have some default files like index.html,index.php,...to redirect and we can rewrite above code as below:

```
http://www.example.com/?a=1&b=2
```

but i dont understand what is this :

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=e
```

this must be :

```
https://www.google.com/search/?q=e
```

are they same ?

Comment: No. One is a page called 'search' while the other is a directory called 'search', which would pass the GET variables to the index page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
http://www.google.com/search
```

would technically be a file called `search`
and this:

```
https://www.google.com/search/
```

a directory called `search` and will usually be rewritten to the `index` file automatically.
Read this article by Google for more info about the so called "trailing slash": http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

Comment: this means that google in his public_html directory (root) has a file named "search" like "test.txt" ?

Comment: No, Google will do this via [rewrites](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html) but technically it WOULD be a file

Answer (score 2):

someurl/?a=2 will call someurl/index.php?a=2

someurl?a=2 will call someurl

Comment: what means "someurl?a=2 will call someurl" ? someurl in a binary file ?

Comment: someurl can be an url which is rewritten. Example: http://www.whatever.com/file?a=2 can call http://www.whatever.com/file.php?a=2

Comment: Your Webserver is usually smart enough to figure out that a directory is meant, if there's no file with the above name

Comment: then google do this work to dont show that what programming language he use ?

Comment: They just do it for "more beautiful URLs", it is known what [Google is written in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754301/what-programming-language-is-google-written-in)

Answer (score 0):

From a strict URL standpoint, no, they are not the same.  Depending on the handler that processes the request, they could give you the same *result*, but they are different URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarely. "search" can be seen as a file without ending, while "search/" can be seen as a folder, where the default page (eg. index.php) will be loaded. It also can be customized with URL rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly,
`http://www.example.com/?a=1&b=2` is a shortcut for `http://www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2`

While `someurl` in `http://www.example.com/someurl?a=1&b=2` is just a resource name, similar to `someurl.php` or `someurl.html` or whatever. a dot is not obligatory for the resource name

Answer (score -1):

Yes, URIs that end in directory names (not file names) are usually treated the same as if you typed a `/` after them. So

```
http://domain.tld/directory
```

and

```
http://domain.tld/directory/
```

are both taken to mean `http://domain.tld/directory/default.file`

And it's the same whether you have a `?` and parameters behind it or not.

In other words, in your examples, `search` is the name of a directory.

Comment: No, they are indeed different, have a look [this statement](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html) by Google. "Google treats each URL above separately"

Comment: then you say this link will work ? https://www.google.com/search/?q=what+is+rose+file&oq=what+is+rose+file&aqs=chrome.0.57j62.2802&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=what+is+.rose+file+login+page&oq=what+is+.rose+file+login+page&gs_l=serp.3...8633.8633.1.8857.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.HMFh2ZYD4-o&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41018144,d.ZG4&fp=65fe59e85b7b1b3b&biw=1280&bih=923

Comment: @Stefan That's why I said "usually" and "treated the same" instead of "always identical". It does depend on the server.

Comment: @anonymous No, actually, I did not say that.